# Nuxt Content 3 - Ignore pages without .json files

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, content-management-system

I'm creating an e-commerce theme with Nuxt 3 content, which will be editable via our CMS. We import the `PageWrapper` component and wrap everything in `app.vue`:

```
<PageWrapper :content="pageContent" :route="route.path">
  <template #login-form>
    <LoginForm :login="login" />
  </template>

  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</PageWrapper>
```

In our `script`, we get `pageContent` like so:

```
const route = useRoute();
  let d = (await queryContent(
    route.path,
  ).findOne()) as unknown as PageContentType;

  const pageContent = ref(d);

  watch(
    () => route.path,
    async () => {
      d = (await queryContent(
        route.path,
      ).findOne()) as unknown as PageContentType;
      console.log(d);
      pageContent.value = d;
    },
  );
```

However, if `pageContent` doesn't exist on a page, I get `404 Document not found!`. This makes sense, since some of our theme pages won't have an associated `.json` file.

For a concrete example, we're going to have product pages, with data being pulled from Firebase. I have a `/products/[id].vue` page and when I add `.` to the front of the file [like the docs say](https://content.nuxt.com/usage/content-directory#ignoring) `/products/.[id].vue` the `404` goes away, but I get `/products/123` not found. I've also tried `/products/.[...slug].vue` to no avail. I don't know if this works on `.vue` files, but it does seem to do *something*.

What's the proper way to ignore whether a `.vue` file has an associated `.json` document or not? If a page doesn't have a `.json` file, I still want it to render.

I'm going to need this for several other pages too, like the cart page, etc. Any help or knowledge on this is appreciated.